# App Crash - <filename unknown>

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I have a pretty simple app. It consists of a viewpager which has 2 pages, within the two pages they have fragments which are custom listviews, these are pre-populated on app load and kept "alive" by using:

```
_viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 2;
```

The listviews have an adapter which inherits from BaseAdapter and I am getting crash reports. I am unable to replicate this locally when debugging, or even when using the app myself.

The stacktrace is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at foo.bar.UserListViewAdaptor.get_Count () <0x9be17c00 + 0x00018> in :0 
>     at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetCount (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) <0x9be17b98 + 0x00037> in :0 
>     at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:aaa28d5c-cd54-4afd-9f37-9496877357de (intptr,intptr)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

I never used to get any crashes/errors, it is only at the time when I have redesigned the app to use a view pager that I have come across this, before it was just a fragment in a single activity and it worked fine. So maybe its something to do with the way viewpagers handle fragments, I just don't know.

Xamarin themselves have moved away from one on one support and moved towards a community support driven environment so suggested posting on SO, but I am not holding my breath in relation to getting support.

If anyone can shed any light I would appreciate it.

EDIT:

Here's the Gist of the UserListViewAdapter:

https://gist.github.com/jaymarvels/4160cebcfcea8639927edfd9d2649d7f

Comment: Can you post your code for the `UserListViewAdapter`? Specifically the `Count` property. Maybe post it in a gist and link here?

Comment: @RyanAlford Edited and added Gist

Answer (score 0):

Going by the stack trace, the `Count` method in the `UserListViewAdapter` is throwing a null reference exception. Since you are only accessing the list of users, I guess it's a possibility that the list is null. I'd probably change that property to...

```
public override int Count
{
    get
    {
        return (_items != null) ? _items.Count : 0;
    }
}
```

Also, at the very least, you should implement the view holder pattern, or switch to using a `RecyclerView`. Calling `FindViewById` is an expensive performance call. Calling it 3 times for every single row when the user scrolls can kill performance.

Comment: is there any reason why this expect would be happening now that the listview fragment is on a viewpager, whereas before it wasn't and this never occurred?

Comment: Not really why it would start happening moving to a view pager.

Comment: will look to implement your suggestion and look if returning 0 when null has any knock on effect. Adding in a viewholder actually seems pretty straight forward.